# Efficient way to extend a numpy array to n*length and duplicate its elements?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for a fast way to take a numpy array, such as `[[1,2,3,4]]`
and turn it into an extended version of itself with its elements repeated `N` times.
I.E. if `N = 2`, then `[[1,2,3,4]]` -> `[[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]]`

Obviously I can brute force it with an explicit for, but I'm wondering if this can be vectorized somehow to speed it up?

edit: i'm using [[1,2,3,4]] as shorthand for np.array([1,2,3,4]), sorry for the confusion. Also, thanks to those of you who mentioned np.repeat! That's just what I needed.

Comment: There's `np.repeat(arr, n, axis=-1)`

Comment: That's not a numpy array

Comment: I'm downvoting because this shows no research on a well hashed-out topic

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from numpy import repeat

x = [[1,2,3,4]]
N = 3
y = repeat(x, N).reshape((1,-1))

print(y)
```

**Edit:** Quang's solution is shorter, I admit ...

```
y = repeat(x, N, axis=-1)
```